# Highstock area chart renders a gap, but there is data

Tags: javascript, html, charts, highcharts

My highstock chart isn't rendering properly. It shows some gap when my 2nd series start in the area chart. Even when zoomed in it's not showing properly. The timestamps are in UTC and have a value.

To clarify it a bit here some screenshots:

Normally not zoomed in:
[image: Normally not zoomed in]

Zoomed in a bit, and showing mouseover. Has only 1 series:
[image: Zoomed in a bit, and showing mouseover. Has only 1 series]

Zoomed in more, showing bigger gap, but has only 1 series:
[image: Zoomed in more, showing bigger gap, but has only 1 series]

Zoomed in more, showing bigger gap, but has only 1 series on same date:
[image: Zoomed in more, showing bigger gap, but has only 1 series on same date]

I have the following options enabled on the graph:

```
chart: {
            zoomType: 'x',
            type: 'area'
        },
plotOptions: {
            area: {
                stacking: 'normal'
            },
            series: {
                turboThreshold: 0,
                dataGrouping: {
                    approximation: "high",
                    smoothed: true,
                    groupPixelWidth: 10,
                    units: [['day', [1]], ['week', [1]], ['month', [1]]]
                }
            }
        }
```

Any suggestions how to resolve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that disabling

```
plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.smoothed
```

does the trick.

So then a bug-report: 
When

```
plotOptions.series.dataGrouping.smoothed = true
```

the graph renders gaps, where I would expect a line.

Comment: Thank you for information about the solution for your issue. If you think it is a bug you can report it on Highcharts github: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues